# rosdep install -a fails on Debian Sqeeze

Tags: debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Following the guide at http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Debian , I get to step 1.5 without issue (as far as I can tell) but when I run rosdep install -a, I get the following:

```
magus:~/ros-underlay/build# rosdep install -a
Executing script below with cwd=/tmp                                                                                                                                                     
{{{                                                                                                                                                                                      
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                              
export PREFIX=/usr/                                                                                                                                                                      
[ f932cebad87302d8ea0ec1fd39b24d99 = `cat $PREFIX/include/eigen3/eigen-version.installed` ]                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                         
}}}                                                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                         
cat: /usr//include/eigen3/eigen-version.installed: No such file or directory                                                                                                             
/tmp/tmpsgnqWw: line 3: [: f932cebad87302d8ea0ec1fd39b24d99: unary operator expected                                                                                                     
Executing script below with cwd=/tmp                                                                                                                                                     
{{{                                                                                                                                                                                      
#!/bin/bash
set -o errexit
dpkg-query -W -f='${Package} ${Status}\n' yaml-cpp-sourcedep 2>&1 | awk '{\
if ($4 =="installed") 
  exit 0
else
  print "yaml-cpp-sourcedep not installed"
  exit 1}'

}}}

yaml-cpp-sourcedep not installed
Executing script below with cwd=/tmp
{{{
#!/bin/bash
export PREFIX=/usr/
if [ -f $PREFIX/include/assimp/assimp-version.installed ]; then
  [ 2ed0b9954bcb2572c0dade8f849b9260 = `cat $PREFIX/include/assimp/assimp-version.installed` ]
else
  false
fi

}}}

ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
rxtools: No definition of [swig-wx] for OS [debian]
image_geometry: No definition of [opencv2] for OS [debian]
image_proc: No definition of [opencv2] for OS [debian]
rviz: No definition of [qt4-qmake] for OS [debian]
image_view: No definition of [opencv2] for OS [debian]
cv_bridge: No definition of [opencv2] for OS [debian]
gazebo: No definition of [tbb] for OS [debian]
image_rotate: No definition of [opencv2] for OS [debian]
opencv2: No definition of [opencv2] for OS [debian]
python_qt_binding: No definition of [python-qt-bindings] for OS [debian]
cv_markers: No definition of [opencv2] for OS [debian]
stereo_image_proc: No definition of [opencv2] for OS [debian]
opencv_tests: No definition of [opencv2] for OS [debian]
turtlesim: No definition of [qt4-qmake] for OS [debian]
depth_image_proc: No definition of [opencv2] for OS [debian]
camera_calibration: No definition of [opencv2] for OS [debian]
pcl_ros: No definition of [pcl] for OS [debian]
```

I can see that yaml-cpp-sourcedep is not installed and it appears that eigen3 might not be either, but I am not sure where these are supposed to come from.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33002/rosdep-install--a-fails-on-debian-sqeeze/) by [mjp](https://answers.ros.org/users/2280/mjp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2012-04-30

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cody](https://answers.ros.org/users/1588/cody/) on 2012-04-30**:
This looks potentially similar to my issue on gentoo (but I don't get any output except the mass of "No definition" errors). http://answers.ros.org/question/32872/ros-fuerte-install-on-gentoo-fails-at-rosdep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I simply went on with the install, installing packages as needed when compilation failed.  rosdep doesn't have files in Fuerte yet for the debian squeeze packages.  I had an Electric install before this one so I just assumed that I had some of these packages.  In the short future, I'll probably file a bug which includes a reasonable rosdep.yaml file.

Some of the ones here are obvious, but pcl and flann I had to compile from the sources.  They are available at https://github.com/wg-debs - you clone the repository you need and then you can install the build dependencies for the package.

For each of the two (I installed flann first, because it was needed for pcl):

1. `git clone https://github.com/wg-debs/flann.git`
2. Remove "unneeded" dependencies from `debian/control` Build-Dependencies (the ones that start with ros- are the only ones I removed)
3. `dpkg-source --commit` (to commit the "extra files" that are there)
4. `git-buildpackage -us -uc --git-ignore-new`
5. `dpkg -i ../*.deb`

There were other small hurdles as well, but they are less of an issue than these two libraries which are custom installed.

---

Originally posted by [jamuraa](https://answers.ros.org/users/534/jamuraa/) with karma: 218 on 2012-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Debian needs some rosdep rules contributed.  [See the howto for that](http://ros.org/doc/api/rosdep2/html/contributing_rules.html)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-05-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1